# Adding multiple rows to table, error

Tags: sql, t-sql

I get this error when running the following code. What am I doing wrong?
I want to add multiple values to the Column Code1. Column Code2 needs to be empty for now.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp2
(Code1 VARCHAR(30), Code2 VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.#Temp2
(Code1)
VALUES ('123') ,('234');
```

The following error I am getting:

```
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Parse error at line: 6, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Your issue cannot be reproduced either on [SQL Server 2014](http://rextester.com/HFDTM5104) nor 2017 on my local instance. Which SQL Server version are you running?

Comment: SELECT @@version gives: Microsoft Parallel Data Warehouse - 10.0.8727.0 (X64) May 8 2018 15:51:34 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Parallel Data Warehouse (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: It can work in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4efcf/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )`